# Backup Messages for Web?

Tags: sms, backup

My phone's screen died, and neither did I root it nor enable USB debugging, so I can't back up my SMS messages the traditional way.

However, I have messages for web (messages.android.com) set up, and can see all my messages there. Is there a way to back this up? If not, is there some API I can use to scrape all my messages?

Comment: If you can manage to enable USB Debugging using mouse with OTG then you can backup using ADB tool.